# Error using longtable and xwatermark

Tags: longtable, watermark

I am experiencing some issues when I use `longtable` and `xwatermark`.

If the table starts in page X and finishes two page later, I get an error : `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` And it points right at the end of the table.

I think it is `xwatermark` that adds something whitin each page that annoys `pdftex`.

If I ignore the error, the file is generated anyway. But I would like to have no error to be able to debug future version easily (I am beggining with LaTeX).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[textheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xwatermark}

\newwatermark[oddpages,fontfamily=,color=gray!25,angle=-90,scale=0.5,xpos=0.45\paperwidth,ypos=0]{\textsc{Confidential}}
\newwatermark[evenpages,fontfamily=,color=gray!25,angle=90,scale=0.5,xpos=-0.45\paperwidth,ypos=0]{\textsc{Confidential}}

\raggedbottom %to prevent Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) with the graphics

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        a & a \\
        \hline
        b & b \\
        \hline
        c & c \\
        \hline
        d & d \\
        \hline
        e & e \\
        \hline
        f & f \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to contain a complete (small) document that shows the error. (You can make set \textheight to a small length in the preamble so you do not need many table rows and watermark with text not an image so the example is self contained)

Comment: I believe the question is about clash betwenn `xwatermark` and `longtable`, hence I removed the other tags.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an example that does the same error

Comment: @tohecz Thanks. I was thinking that maybe it was texworks or texmaker responsible as the file was generated at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `longtable` is already centered by default. Remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` and you are bailed out.